# I need to know whether a matrix is rotating or mirror of another

Tags: javascript, matrix

I am new to the world of programming, and  I have to make a function that given two matrix nxn (matrix a, matrix b) it  tell me if the matrix b is rotating of the matrix a  or if matrix b is the mirror matrix

function receives a matrix of this style [[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,0]],I am new to the world of programming javascript

Can you give you some ideas of how to do it?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry I did not express well, I get a style matrix [[0,0] [1,0] [1,1] [0,1]] and the other rotated matrix is of the form [[0,1] [0,0] [1,0] [1,1]], the detail is that the values are within the matrix of a matrix point. the only thing that occurred to me at the moment is to treat the matrix as if you were represented in memory and juggle the values to their new position, but bigger is the largest the jumps are @Bonatti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the following:

> var arrayA= [ [0,1],[2,3],[4,5] ]; // 2x2 matrix
>
> var arrayB= [ [0,1],[2,3],[4,5] ]; // 2x2 matrix equal to arrayA
>
> var arrayB= [ [0,1],[2,3],[4,6] ]; // 2x2 matrix not equal to arrayA

Then, you must now have a "rotating" function

```
function isRotating(a,b){
if(a.length == 0 || b.length == 0 || a[0].length == 0||b[0].length==0){
    return false;
} else {
    var m=a.length;
    var n=a[0].length;
    for(var i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(a[i][j]!=b[i][j]){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
return true;
}
```

> Now note that this will do a LOT of operations, so , if you have 2 (10x10) matrices, you will do (10*10)*(10*10) = 10000 operations, thus blocking the script then failing...

It is up to you know understand what you must execute, then lower the operations and maximize your script

```
alert("A == B => "+isRotating(arrayA,arrayB));
alert("A == C => "+isRotating(arrayA,arrayC));
```